# Capistrano 3 Sudo Password Hangs

Tags: capistrano3, whenever

I have the following capistrano 3 task:

```
desc 'Add root scheduled tasks'
task :root_schedules do
  on roles(:all) do 
    within release_path do
      execute :sudo, :bundle, 'exec whenever -w config/root_schedule.rb -u root'
    end
  end
end
```

I need this task to run with sudo privileges because I need the scheduled tasks to run with higher privileges. These are backend scheduled server tasks. Problem is that everytime I run this command I get following:

```
DEBUG [46d3800c]    [sudo] password for [user]
```

After I type my password and hit enter, it never completes anything. No response at all. Any answers out there?

Answer (score 19):

I just created a gem for this purpose: [sshkit-sudo](https://github.com/kentaroi/sshkit-sudo)

1. Add `gem 'sshkit-sudo'` to Gemfile
2. Add `require 'sshkit/sudo'` to Capfile

Now you can use `sudo` command in your Capistrano 3 task.

Comment: I've read info but I'm still wondering how does your gem get sudo password? Does it prompt for it?

Comment: @AlexanderGorg Yes. When a remote server prompts you to input your sudo password, the gem waits for you to type it.

Comment: I'm so grateful to you! It's a really cool gem! I wish you all the best!

Comment: @AlexanderGorg My pleasure. Your words made my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano kinda expects you to have this handled with a sudoers file, [link](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#authorisation) so that password input is not required.

The direct answer to the question is: capistrano probably uses the default non-login, non-interactive shell. Since the shell is non-interactive, that probably explains why user input is ignored.
Read more about this [here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/).